# UILinebreakmode not working for a UILabel in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I have a UILabel for which there are many lines.The number of lines depends at runtime.
But my UILineBreakmode is not working properly..

This is the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *temp=@"";

    for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
    {


        temp=[temp stringByAppendingString:[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Specilities"]];
        temp=[temp stringByAppendingString:@","];
    } 
    temp = [temp substringToIndex:[temp length]-1];
CGSize constraint8 = CGSizeMake(190, 2000.0f);
CGSize size8=[temp sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint8 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
specialities =[[UILabel alloc]init];
[specialities setFrame:CGRectMake(124,270,190, size8.height)];
specialities.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
specialities.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
specialities.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
specialities.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",temp ];
specialities.numberOfLines=0;
[specialities sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:specialities];   
}

Expected result:

Family Dentistry,Dentist-
Child,Dentist-Family,
Orthodontist 

The result which Im getting:

Family Dentistry,Dentist-
Child,Dentist-Family,Orthodo
ntist
```

How can I get it ?

Comment: Where is your `temp`'s definition? I set `temp` to your expected string and successfully get what you expect.

Comment: I  edited my code.Can u please have a look ...

Answer (score 2):

Try experimenting with the lineBreakMode property of UILabel.
For example, try this on your label:

```
specialities.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

the possible options are:
(see the Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSLineBreakByWordWrapping) for mor details)

```
enum {
   NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
   NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
   NSLineBreakByClipping,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
};
typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode
```

try experimenting with the various settings.

Comment: Where should I write this:enum {
   NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
   NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
   NSLineBreakByClipping,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
};
typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode

Comment: no, no! the enum values are the possible options for the lineBreakMode property, from the Apple documentation! in your code you write "specialities.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;" and check the result! If the result is not satisfying you try with the next option, like "specialities.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;" etc.! But NSLineBreakByWordWrapping should be the option you need in my opinion!